# Apache: how to double-decode double-encoded incoming URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, urldecode

I'm having an issue with my Rails app running under Passenger/Apache, where Googlebot is attempting to access URLs where the query string parameters have been double-encoded. (I have no idea where Googlebot is getting these URLs from -- they're not in any links anywhere on my app.)

This is resulting in a lot of extra errors in my logs, making it very difficult to diagnose "real" issues since they're buried underneath the errors cause by the URLs Googlebot is trying to access.

Here's an example from my Apache access logs:

> 66.249.67.103 - - [27/Oct/2014:07:44:32 -0400] "GET /catalog?f%255Bfacet_field_1%255D%255B%255D=foo&f%255Bfacet_field_2%255D%255B%255D=bar&sort=title_info_primary_ssort+asc%252C+date_start_dtsi+asc
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 5266 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

Notice the double encoding ("%255B", "%255D"), which is the encoded version of already-encoded characters ("%5B", "%5D"). So instead of my Rails app receiving these parameters:

```
{
  "f[facet_field_1][]" => "foo",
  "f[facet_field_2][]" => "bar",
  "sort" => "title_info_primary_ssort asc, date_start_dtsi asc"
}
```

...it receives these:

```
{
  "f%5Bfacet_field_1%5D%5B%5D" => "foo",
  "f%5Bfacet_field_2%5D%5B%5D" => "bar",
  "sort"=>"title_info_primary_ssort asc%2C date_start_dtsi asc"
}
```

... which it can't interpret, leading to lots of entries in the error logs. The URL is being decoded once (pretty sure Apache does this by default), but that still leaves URL-encoded characters in the parameters hash that Rails can't deal with.

What I need is a way to double-decode URLs where the user agent is Googlebot. It seems like one should be able to do this using mod_rewrite, but I'm not having much luck, as mod_rewrite doesn't seem well-suited for modifying the query string portion of the URL. It's also problematic because I can't predict the exact order of the parameters, nor the exact combination of parameters that might be being passed in the URL.

How can I tell Apache to double-decode the URL (based on the user agent) before it passes the request to my application? (Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)). Blocking Googlebot is not an acceptable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is way to do it, but it requires modification of the server's `.conf` file. You need to add to the server configuration the following directive:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape
```

After that you can use RewriteRule as something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?${unescape:%{QUERY_STRING}} [L]
```

And, as I think, it should be done not for every request, but only for those that need to be decoded, so additional RewriteCond is required. You can check, for example, the presence of `%255B`, `%255D` and so on.

So, the final set of rules will be (it may be triggered in case of presence of the double-quoted symbols in the values of the elements, not just in the names of the parameters)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %255(B|D)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?${unescape:%{QUERY_STRING}} [L]
```

Comment: This works well -- thanks! FWIW, I ended up deciding to return a 400 Bad Request response to these Googlebot requests instead of redirecting them as if the parameters had been properly encoded:
'RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %25[25][BC]
RewriteRule . - [R=400,L]'